# Detect click outside QLineEdit

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qlineedit

My complex GUI consists of many native and custom widgets. Most of them has no focus at all (i don't need it: for example, some display-only widgets that doesn't need user's input).

Sometimes `QLineEdit` appears on the screen when GUI want user to input some string (imagine window's Explorer after pressing F2 having some file selected (rename).

I want user to be able to close this `QLineEdit` as many ways as possible: pressing Enter, ESC, clicking outside the QLineEdit.

1. `QLineEdit` sends `editingFinished()` signal in some circumstances (press Enter, click on another widget);
2. Also i can make new class derived from `QLineEdit` that sends `editingFinished()` signal when `focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent *)` occurs.
3. In that class I can catch ESC key and send the `editingFinished()`.

The only problem is that `QLineEdit` loses focus only if some another widget takes the focus. So if you click to a widget that doesn't care about focus, the `QLineEdit` stay having focus and doesn't send the `editingFinished()` signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to install an event filter for your entire app, that sends a custom event to all your `lineEdits` when a mouse click happens.  And then in the `lineEdit`, and implement `QObject::event()` for your `lineEdit` class checking for that custom event if it is active or has focus.

I wrote up an answer that points to the documentation for filters like this:

[Catching Qt modifier key releases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747991/catching-qt-modifier-key-releases/11026014#11026014)

Hope that helps.